# Magento2 file could not be downloaded: Failed to open stream: Network is unreachable

Tags: magento2, composer

> The
> "http://repo.packagist.org/p/paypal/module-braintree-graph-ql%245690cb72028a8444b0f87c92557cb7e772f5e673c323118e1a18304afae1eb14.json"
> file could not be downloaded:      Failed to open stream: Network is
> unreachable

I am getting this error when running composer update cmd in Magento2.

I already tried by deleting the composer lock, vendor, clear cache etc..

Please help how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're encountering, "Network is unreachable," indicates that Composer is having trouble connecting to the Packagist repository to download a package. This issue can be caused by various factors, including network issues, firewall settings, or temporary problems on the Packagist server. Here's a step-by-step guide to help you resolve this issue:

1. **Check Your Network Connection**:

   - Ensure that your server has an active and stable internet connection. Try pinging external websites (e.g., `ping google.com`) to verify connectivity.
2. **Firewall and Proxy Settings**:

   - If your server uses a firewall or a proxy, make sure that Composer is configured to use the correct proxy settings. You can set these in your `composer.json` file or through environment variables.
   - Example of proxy settings in `composer.json`:

     ```json
     "config": {
         "http-proxy": "http://proxy.example.com:8080",
         "https-proxy": "http://proxy.example.com:8080"
     }
     ```
3. **Check Packagist Status**:

   - Sometimes, the issue might be on the Packagist side. Check the status of Packagist at https://status.packagist.org/ to see if there are any ongoing issues.
4. **Composer Self-Update**:

   - Ensure that you are using the latest version of Composer. Run the following command to update Composer itself:

     ```
     composer self-update
     ```
5. **Composer Configuration**:

   - Check your Composer configuration to ensure it's correctly set up. You can check the global Composer configuration by running:

     ```
     composer config -l
     ```

     Review the values to make sure there are no conflicting settings.
6. **PHP Version Compatibility**:

   - Verify that your PHP version is compatible with the Magento 2 version you're working with. Composer might have difficulty resolving dependencies if there's a PHP version mismatch.
7. **Try a Different Repository**:

   - If the issue persists, consider changing the repository URL in your `composer.json` file to use a mirror or a different repository, although this is not recommended for long-term use:

     ```json
     "repositories": [
         {
             "type": "composer",
             "url": "https://packagist.org-mirror.com/packagist.org"
         }
     ]
     ```
8. **Clear Composer Cache**:

   - Sometimes, Composer caches files that may be causing issues. Clear the Composer cache with the following command:

     ```
     composer clear-cache
     ```
9. **Check for DNS Issues**:

   - Ensure that your server has correct DNS settings and can resolve domain names. Try running `nslookup packagist.org` to verify DNS resolution.
10. **Server Maintenance**:

    - Sometimes, package servers undergo maintenance, which can temporarily disrupt downloads. Wait for a while and try running `composer update` again later.
11. **Contact Your Hosting Provider**:

    - If you're using a shared hosting environment, your hosting provider might have restrictions that affect Composer's ability to make network requests. Contact them for assistance if necessary.

After trying these steps, attempt to run `composer update` again to see if the issue is resolved. If you're still facing problems, you may want to consult with Magento support or community forums for specific Magento-related troubleshooting steps.